# Domain Driven Design - Inheritance in ValueObjects

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot, value-objects

```
User <AggregateRoot>{
  name: String;
  paymentType: PaymentType;
}

PaymentType <ValueObject> {
  //Common attributes
}
```

1. Can the above PaymentType(ValueObject) be inherited by these ValueObjects(Subclasses) - Credit, Cash, Cheque ?
2. There is a domain invariant that says, User can have one PaymentType at a time. Should this go into the User(AggregateRoot) or PaymentType(ValueObject) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the above PaymentType(ValueObject) be inherited by these ValueObjects(Subclasses) - Credit, Cash, Cheque ?

Maybe.  Inheritance is largely an implementation detail.

But it's not clear to me that's the question you are really asking.  Your example looks a bit like trying to design a "union type", which is to say a handle that you can use to match different patterns.

Scott Wlaschin has an example of a [PaymentMethod union type](https://www.slideshare.net/ScottWlaschin/domain-driven-design-with-the-f-type-system-functional-londoners-2014?ref=https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ddd/#62) in his domain modeling made functional slide deck.  His blog series on [designing with types](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-intro/) describes the technique in more detail using other examples.

> There is a domain invariant that says, User can have one PaymentType at a time. Should this go into the User(AggregateRoot) or PaymentType(ValueObject) ?

It depends.  The code for deciding which state transitions are permitted normally goes into the thing that owns the state (in this example, the User).  How we *represent* state, the actual data structures and so on, often live in Value Objects.

The modeling patterns described in chapter 5 (entities, value objects) and chapter 6 (aggregates, repositories) are just patterns.  There are no prizes awarded for applying those patterns most perfectly.  The main goal in implementing the domain model is still the same: to produce code designs that can be changed smoothly to match the changing needs of the domain.

Comment: Those 2 links are useful, thanks for sharing.Do you have any alternative solution instead of creating union types? Also, which book you are referring here(Chapter 5 and Chapter 6)?

Comment: Eric Evans, Domain-Driven Design (2003).

Comment: Thanks @VoiceOfUnreason. Do you have any alternative solution instead of creating union types?